# htdocs and fcgi python in subdirectory

Tags: lighttpd

I want to use a Flask Python script in a subdirectory under Lighttpd, because htdocs contains a lot of static files. I have a working solution where the Flask application is called below "/". The configuration looks like this:

```
fastcgi.server = ("/api.fcgi" =>
((
    "socket" => "/tmp/evalutation-fcgi.sock",
    "bin-path" => var.basedir + "/api.fcgi",
    "check-local" => "disable",
    "max-procs" => 1
)) )

url.rewrite-once = ( "^(/.+)$" => "/api.fcgi$1" )
```

I tried to adjust the regular expression for URL rewrite:

```
url.rewrite-once = ( "^(/api/.+)$" => "/api.fcgi$1" )
```

but I don't get the REST API from Flask anymore and get a 404 HTTP error. The static files are reachable.

My goal is that the endpoints of the Flask application are only reachable under "/api/", all files are reachable under htdocs. So my question is how to adjust the rewrite definition.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want `url.rewrite-once = ( "^/api(/.+)$" => "/api.fcgi$1" )`

(Note that I put the /api outside the regex capturing parens)

Comment: Thanks, that was the solution

Comment: (If the solution is correct, please accept the solution so that others can find it more easily in searches)

Comment: Thanks for the replay and sorry for my late answer, but this regular expression works fine